# Strange behavior of `/proc/self/environ` in some shells; what is going on?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, environment-variables, proc

I'm on Debian GNU/Linux 9. I know [`/proc` is special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), I know [what `/proc/self` is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333225/108618).

This command

```
sh -c '/bin/cat /proc/self/comm - </proc/self/comm'
```

yields

```
cat
sh
```

The pattern will be similar if I use `dash` instead of `sh`. But with `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh` the result is

```
cat
cat
```

Taking `/proc/self/stat` instead of `/proc/self/comm` I can confirm the two `cat`-s are in fact the same single process. Apparently shells differ under the hood, it's OK. Now let's take

```
sh -c '/bin/cat /proc/self/environ - </proc/self/environ'
```

Having observed the above, with `sh` or `dash` I expect to see the environment of the `cat` first, the environment of the shell later. It seems to work (both environments are most likely identical anyway so it's hard to tell if *everything* works as expected, but my point is: neither `environ` is empty).

With `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh` I expect to see the environment of the `cat` twice, but it's only printed *once*. Splitting into two separate cases:

- `bash -c '/bin/cat - </proc/self/environ'` prints nothing, as if `environ` was empty;
- `bash -c '/bin/cat /proc/self/environ'` prints something as expected.

What is going on? This is not the case with `comm` or `stat`. Why is `environ` different?

```
$ uname -a
Linux barbaz 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1 (2018-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The differences between shells are due to differences in process setup. `dash` sets redirections up before forking, so `/proc/self` points at the shell; `bash` and `zsh` set them up after forking, so `/proc/self` points at the new process. You can see this happen with `strace -f`:

- `strace -f dash -c '/bin/cat /proc/self/comm - </proc/self/comm'` shows (among many other things)

  ```
    open("/proc/self/comm", O_RDONLY)       = 3
    fcntl(0, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
    close(0)                                = 0
    fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
    dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f12581299d0) = 7743
    strace: Process 7743 attached
    [pid  7742] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
    [pid  7743] execve("/bin/cat", ["/bin/cat", "/proc/self/comm", "-"], [/* 43 vars */]) = 0
  ```

  (`/proc/self/comm` is opened before the `clone` system call, which is where the process forks);
- `strace -f bash -c '/bin/cat /proc/self/comm - </proc/self/comm'` shows

  ```
    clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fb506bdee10) = 8106
    strace: Process 8106 attached
    [... snip a ton of signal-handling setup ...]
    [pid  8106] open("/proc/self/comm", O_RDONLY) = 3
    [pid  8106] dup2(3, 0)                  = 0
    [pid  8106] close(3)                    = 0
    [pid  8106] execve("/bin/cat", ["/bin/cat", "/proc/self/comm", "-"], [/* 43 vars */]) = 0
  ```

  (`/proc/self/comm` is opened after the `clone` call, in the child process, 8106).

Understanding why `environ` shows up empty requires a bit more explanation. [When `/proc/<pid>/environ` is opened](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/base.c?id=f6d2f584d88616e27eeb603dc8c88ca16e00d682#n882), the kernel [saves a copy of the pointer to the task’s `mm_struct`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/base.c?id=f6d2f584d88616e27eeb603dc8c88ca16e00d682#n769), which contains pointers to the environment. But [`execve`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/exec.c?id=0214f46b3a0383d6e33c297e7706216b6a550e4b#n1709), which is used to start the `cat` process, [creates a new `mm_struct` for the process](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/exec.c?id=0214f46b3a0383d6e33c297e7706216b6a550e4b#n398). Thus the redirection ends up pointing at obsolete information and when `cat` reads its input it doesn’t see its real environment. The environment it *does* see should be a copy of its parent’s, but the shells involved clean it up before forking and setting up the new environment (which is set up by `execve`).

Comment: `zsh` and `ksh93` would run `cat` in the same process (no need to fork as it's the last command in the inline script). `bash` does it only when the inline script has only  one command and without redirections (compare `bash -c ps` with `bash -c 'true; ps'` or `bash -c 'ps < /dev/null'`). IIRC Some versions of `dash` had the same optimisation but that was reverted as it was bogus.