# Is there a library call or syscall to set /proc/self/oom_score_adj?

Tags: out-of-memory

I have an important process that the OOM Killer has taken a fancy to with unfortunate results.  I would like to make this less likely.  All google turns up is stuff like:

```
echo -1000 > /proc/${PID}/oom_score_adj
```

while I would like to do it in the program source itself.  Is there a library call or syscall to do this, or is my only option `getpid()`, `open()`, `write()` & `close()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no system call, or library function, as far as I’m aware. No need for `getpid()` though, you can open [`/proc/self/oom_score_adj`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333225/86440) directly.