# Subprocess launched inside a chroot created on a codespace with debootstrap fail with /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, chroot, debootstrap

My goal is to standup a chroot with the basic Unix tool-set (`bash`, `cp`, `touch`, `cat`, etc) and any necessary dependencies need to run `apt get` inside a codespace. Using debootstrap gets me close. The basic tools are installed and I can run `apt get`. The problem is subprocess do not work. I expect the last line to print "test" but actually I get an error saying that the subprocess' file handle is no good. I would have thought the vanilla debootstrap environment would be sufficiently cooked so that subprocess work, but that does not seem to be the case. Is there a switch I can pass?

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install -y binutils debootstrap
$ cd /home/codespace
$ CHROOT=/home/codespace/chroot
$ mkdir -p "${CHROOT}"
$ sudo debootstrap stable "${CHROOT}" http://deb.debian.org/debian/
$ sudo chroot "${CHROOT}"
$ cat < <(echo test)
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

To reproduce,

- sign up for codespaces beta [here](https://github.com/features/codespaces/signup).
- fire up a codespace for [this project](https://github.com/kingces95/chroot-mounts), open a bash shell (ctrl+`).
- run the above.

This also reproduces outside of codespace so any Ubuntu environment will probably yield similar results.

Comment: See also discussion here: https://github.com/orgs/github-community/discussions/19714#discussioncomment-3056844

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086617/dev-fd-63-no-such-file-or-directory. The post implies the after the last colon is emanating from the subproc. In my case the subproc is simply and echo statement so I don't see how that could generated "No such file or directory." I could replace the echo statement with a null statement -- just a colon and see if that changes anything.

Comment: The directory `/proc/$$` is not resolving. This [SO post answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333271/437828) discusses what `/proc/self` is and is not. Whatever it is, it isn't work in my chroot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/417004/1231105). Turns out `/proc` was not mounted. To mount proc I ran

```
$ cd "${CHROOT}"
$ sudo mount --types proc /proc proc/
```

Now things work!

```
$ cat < <(echo test)
test
```